# Cleats for Shimano PD 1056 pedals

Tags: shimano, cleat

I've bought an old racing bike with Shimano PD 1056 pedals installed and I am in need to buy cleats compatible with these. G****e search for "PD 1056 cleats" reveal SHIMANO SM-SH11 SPD-SL cleats, but I could not find the pedals in any compatibility list für these cleats.

Are these both compatible or is there a better suggestion?

Here are some photos of the pedals:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: All SPD cleats are interchangeable, so it is likely that they work. However, I don't know what you mean by G***e, but Google does not find any pedals numbered PD 1506.

Comment: Yeah, to my mind, Google is taking the "PD" and "cleats" and turning up modern cleats because they still use PD to name all their pedals. Searching for the PD1506 pedals I can't find any results, they must be too old for casual searches. Try adding a photograph of the pedals here using [edit] so we can see what they look like for a start. I would not suggest buying SM-SH11 just yet

Comment: Edited my question accordingly, and I just realised that unfortunately - mea culpa - I permuted two digits in the model number, its PD 1056, **NOT** PD 1506.

Comment: That looks like an old Look pedal.  It doesn't look like a current SPD-SL cleat would work.

Comment: Yes, Shimano made some licensed Look clones before developing SPD variants. http://www.bikepro.com/products/pedals/shimlook.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These pedals will take the old style Look Delta cleats, NOT the Keo-type. The cleats are readily available from Look retailers. You can have them with the same specifications as the Keo cleats, in black, grey and red with 0°, 3° and 6° sideways free rotation.

Be aware though that the pedals have built-in sideways freedom of movement, toggled by the slotted screw at the rear so that it's not a good idea to buy the grey or red type. Probably too much of the good!